# Me almacena todo pero solo me muestra el ultimo

Tags: java, android

tengo un problema y no lo e podido resolver, obviamente estoy mal pero no me e podido percatar de mi error, la cosa esta asi quiero mandar a imprimir en un QR un encabezado y un contenido el cual contiene Barcode y Quantity, al momento de meter el resultado en un arreglo se ve que si los almacena pero al llamar la variable en el cual almacene el contenido en String solo me manda el ultimo. alguien que me pueda ayudar, se los agradeceria mucho. PS no soy muy bueno en Android Studio hago lo que puedo jaja.

```
    public void showList(List<LineItem> list) {

    saleList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    for (LineItem line : list) {
        saleList.add(line.toMap());
    }

    SimpleAdapter sAdap;
    sAdap = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), saleList,
            listview_lineitem, new String[]{"name", "quantity", "price", "numProvider"},
            new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.quantity, R.id.price, numProvider});
    saleListView.setAdapter(sAdap);


    Iterator<LineItem> productosI = list.iterator();

    String[] arProd = new String[list.size()];

   while (productosI.hasNext()) {
       for(int i =0; i<arProd.length;i++) {
           arProd[i] = productosI.next().ordernarArticulos();
       }

    }
    for(String eProd : arProd)
    {
        txtQR1 = eProd;
        Log.i("Contenido",txtQR1);
    }


    for (LineItem e : list) {

        txtQR2 = e.ordenarEncabezado() ;

    }

    txtQR = txtQR2 + txtQR1+">";
    Log.i("Contenido1",txtQR);

    }


    public void showPopup(View anchorView) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("edttext", totalPrice.getText().toString());
    bundle.putString("arraylist",txtQR);
    PaymentFragmentDialog newFragment = new PaymentFragmentDialog(SaleFragment.this, reportFragment);
    newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "");
}
```

Esta es otra clase donde cree los metodos

```
    public String ordenarEncabezado() {
    Date horaActual = new Date();
    String hora =(horaActual.getYear()+1900)+""+(horaActual.getMonth()+1)+""+horaActual.getDate();
    //for(int i=0;i<)



    return "<<TTX"+"F"+getId()+"M01"+"P"+numProvider+"D"+ hora + ">";

}

public String ordernarArticulos(){


    return "<C"+product.getBarcode()+"Q"+quantity+">";




}
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Miguel, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** en base a este documento modifica tu pregunta, saludos!

Comment: En que parte ser realiza esto : "al llamar la variable en el cual almacene el contenido en String solo me manda el ultimo."

Comment: }

    txtQR = txtQR2 + txtQR1+">";  //txtQR1 es donde esta almacenado 
    Log.i("Contenido1",txtQR);

    }

Comment: Ok, siempre muestra el último @MiguelFlores.  Cual es el que deseas ver?

Comment: en realidad necesito que me muestre todos ya sean 3 o 30 y me doy cuenta que si los esta almacenando por el Log.i y estos son los resultados que me arroja         <C1Q1>
01-12 13:42:26.732 19869-19869/Contenido: <C3Q1>
01-12 13:42:26.732 19869-19869/Contenido1: <<TTXF158M01P6969D2018112><C3Q1>> //lo primero es el encabezado y lo segundo es lo que necesito que me muestre cuantas veces exista en la lista pero como vez me agarra solo el ultimo

Comment: Ya tubo solucion solo tuve que utilizar un StringBuffer en vez de un for each para recorrer el arreglo arProd